# Filter out object from a certain namespace

Tags: c#, types, reflection, namespaces

I have a `List<BaseType> objects` that I need to work with.

For most derived types, what I do works perfectly, but for some reason, certain derived types from a certain namespace don't work well (unsolvable problem regarding external libraries).

Is there a way I can filter out all objects from that namespace?

Comment: Something like `objects.Where(x => !x.GetType().Namespace.StartsWith("unwanted.namesapce"))` perhaps?

Comment: If you have control over the filling of this list, it would probably be better to do the filtering there as you'll most likely have to use reflection. If you have control over the namespace in question, you can create another `BaseType2 : BaseType` specifically for all the objects in that namespace, then just check for `item is not BaseType2`. Otherwise, I think you just have to do a `item.GetType().FullName.StartsWith(...)`

Comment: The reflection solution proposed by @CamiloTerevinto works. I'd accept that as an answer. I don't believe there would be a different approach regarding namespaces without reflection, but that approach would be preferred. I have absolutely no control over the types, they're third party types.